# How to find the download URL of a specific package/port in FreeBSD's repository?

Tags: freebsd, freebsd-ports

I'm trying to find the full URL for downloading the Emby Server .txz package from FreeBSD repository, but I got no luck finding it on any search engines.

Farther I went was this FreeBSD repository list https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/ports.cgi?query=emby-server&stype=all but I could not find any URL in there.

My intention is to add and install this package directly through the URL, like this:

```
pkg add http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:12:amd64/latest/All/emby-server1.1.1.txz
```

I'm using FreeBSD 12, amd64.

Comment: And you cannot use `pkg install emby-server`? Are you looking for a specific version?

Comment: What is the benefit of `add` in your case?

Comment: Yes, the intention is to install a specific version of the software. I forgot tô mention that I am using PfSense's FreeBSD, and that's why I cant use pkg install directly. The add command is needed for adding the package to PfSense internal package list.

Comment: You can run version hell (versions of dependencies of emby-server maybe different on your host). I think you should try to add a package repository and simply `pkg install`.

Comment: I can't simply use `pkg install` because I am using PfSense modified version of FreeBSD. The allowed way of installing packages is by informing its URL.
Version hell is really a problem though but I am willing to give it a try.

Comment: Same case with pfSense, I just needed some packages for diagnostics and per default there also is no version hell in pfSense since everything installed this way will be dropped on the next update. Straightforward and useful but an easy way to find the URLs is missing - I found my packages with trail and error knowing the versions beforehand but I would still be interested in a better way.

Answer (score 1):

To find the URL endpoint that your FreeBSD packages are being downloaded from, you can do `ls /etc/pkg/` to get a list of repos that your system is currently configured to use. There should be a `.conf` file for each repo, and the default is `/etc/pkg/FreeBSD.conf`.
For example, the URL for mine is `pkg+http://pkg.FreeBSD.org/${ABI}/quarterly`.
If I was installing nginx on my current setup, it would grab it from:
`http://pkg.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:14:amd64/quarterly/All/nginx-1.24.0_12,3.pkg`

If you have trust issues and want to be 100% sure where the .pkg files are being downloaded from on FreeBSD, you can use Wireshark or something similar to inspect your http/1.1 traffic and find the endpoint url where the .pkg file is being fetched from.

For example, my other FreeBSD server was fetching Apache Traffic Server from:
`http://pkgmir.geo.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:14:amd64/quarterly/All/trafficserver-9.2.1.pkg`

If you want to install a FreeBSD .pkg file from a remote server without adding an entire repo, you may do:
`pkg add http://pkgmir.geo.freebsd.org/FreeBSD:14:amd64/quarterly/All/trafficserver-9.2.1.pkg`
That would be `pkg add http(s)://{domain}.{tld}/{path_to}.pkg`

For more information, I find the following page to be the most helpful. https://github.com/freebsd/pkg/blob/master/README.md